# How to Connect Site Collection Admin through Custom FBA login page - Sharepoint Site

Tags: .net, sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

I have thousand of users to login as normal users for my SharePoint site 2013.There fore i added FBA authentication.Configured done.

but i needed to have custom login page for FBA users.Then i added custom login page for FBA user login.Now any user can login through the custom login page.

but my problem is how **site collection admin** login to the site right after.I cannot use the default FBA user login page with dropdown contains **windows authentication** and **FBA authentication.** I do not need to see the end user such drop down to select.

Can i have 2 separate SharePoint site links for admin and normal FBA users? or any other solution?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the web application to 2 separate zones (Each has a different url).  Then you can set the one zone to handle only FBA, and the other to only handle Windows users.  Depending on what url the user went to would determine the type of authenticaiton.

Alternatively, if you prefer to keep a single url for your site, you can develop a custom login page.  The page would have the login form for the FBA users as well as a 'Windows Login' button/link that would redirect the user to the windows login page.

Also, if it's only your site collection admin that you need to login, you can set an FBA user as a site collection admin, and they could login with FBA.

Comment: Chris,I think extending the site to 2 separate URL is better.Can you please give some reference to do that.

Comment: Central Admin -> Manage Web applications -> Select Web Application -> 'Extend'.  That will create your seperate zone/url.

To edit the authentication settings for existing zones, just use the 'Authentication Providers' button.